# Linq to Sql Insertion conflict with "Foreign Key Same Table constraint" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq 2 Sql to knock out a quick bespoke CMS.

I have a table with an association to itself, so that any children menus are mapped to any parent menus within the same table, but I am having an issue inserting the first parent.

The table looks a little like this:

```
CMSMenu
     CMSMenuID
     ParentCMSMenuID    
     Name
     Link
```

With an association of

```
CMSMenu.CMSMenuID -> CMSMenu.ParentCMSMenuID
```

In a previous version of the database/code I would simply add some code like:

```
  itm = new CMSMenu();
  itm.ParentCMSMenuID = 0; 
  rep.CMSMenus.InsertOnSubmit(itm);
```

But as this database was created automatically with all the foreign keys, this code causes an exception:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE
>   constraint "CMSMenu_CMSMenu". The conflict occurred in database
>   "sp.ackahs", table "dbo.CMSMenu", column 'CMSMenuID'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

How do I insert the top level menu (ie with no parent)?

As it does not have a parent so I cannot add:

```
itm.MyParentCMSMenu=*existing cmsmenu item*;
```

As I could with a child menu, nor can I add:

```
itm.MyParentCMSMenu=null;
```

Any thoughts welcome.

Thanks
Toby

Comment: Can you set MyParentCMSMenu to be a nullable column in the SQL?

Comment: Yup.... I feel a bit of a fool, I was expecting this is cause an error in the association as CMSMenuID would not be nullable and ParentCMSMenuID would be. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting MyParentCMSMenu to be a nullable column in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a special version of CMSMenu item is used. It may be named "null" and have ID 0 or 1. It should be used as parent of items that in fact have no parent. And it should be filtered out from all queries.

That is one of weaknesses of relational databases -- you need to use all sort of quirks to store simple abstractions like trees.